# Google App Engine: "Error: no module named numpy.distutils.core" while deploying an app

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, google-app-engine, importerror, python-module

I've read several questions about deploying Python applications on GAE, but I still couldn't manage to make my own work. First I thought it was because of my `requirements.txt` file and my `lib` folder, but then I discovered (through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885155/python-virtualenv-no-module-error)) I was messing the configurations and to flexible environments you should use only the requirements file (I may have misunderstood this too, so if I'm wrong please tell me).

I have this `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: python
api_version: 1
env: flex
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: app.app 

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2

entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -b $HOST:$PORT app:app
```

And this is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
enum34==1.1.6
Flask==1.0.2
funcsigs==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.7
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
llvmlite==0.24.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
numba==0.39.0
numpy==1.15.0
pycparser==2.18
PySoundFile==0.9.0.post1
requests==2.19.1
resampy==0.2.1
scikits.talkbox==0.2.5
scipy==1.1.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
SoundFile==0.10.2
urllib3==1.23
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

The error I'm always getting is

> Step #1: Collecting scikits.talkbox==0.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
>   Step #1:   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/a0/410eb932e1765186a4728d1c9b28410695d554c47439bcb69a407d5d3921/scikits.talkbox-0.2.5.tar.gz (151kB)
>   Step #1:     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>   Step #1:     Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Step #1:       File "", line 1, in 
>   Step #1:       File "/tmp/pip-build-3zN00W/scikits.talkbox/setup.py", line 10, in 
>   Step #1:         from numpy.distutils.core import setup
>   Step #1:     ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

So, after doing some research, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212486/error-installing-scikits-audiolab-when-using-python-setup-py-egg-info) that shows kind of a "hack" to bypass this problem, the only thing is that it'll make no difference changing it locally. I have no problem running my application locally.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so apparently the only solution I could find was to change the `runtime` parameter in `app.yaml` to `custom` and then creating a Dockerfile with my configs.

I still don't know why `scikits.talkbox` won't install corretly through my `requirements.txt`, but I found out that using

```
RUN pip install scikits.talkbox
```

in my Dockerfile and removing it from my requirements file was enough to make it work. I would be glad to know if anyone could make it happen otherwise, because I'm really curious about this.

Now my `app.yaml` now looks like this:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```